# C++ Live Sound Control

Tags: c++, audio, instruments, volume, pitch

In C++ compiled with Visual Studio 2008 or 2010, am looking for a way to play a note on an instrument and then be able to change the pitch of that note (i.e. from a C to a D), its volume, and even the instrument that plays it in a program.

I know this sounds a lot like MIDI, but I'm not sure how to accomplish it. I would be fine or even prefer using a 3rd party program such as CSound, but again don't know how and cannot figure it out.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: Using CSound is easy, but how do I control CSound through Visual Studio?

Comment: This is a very broad-scope question, which makes it hard to answer. Are you looking for a MIDI library? Or a full product like Propellerhead's Reason?

Answer (score 1):

You need a C++ music synthesizer framework, such as:

- CLAM: http://clam-project.org/index.html
- STK: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/
- SuperCollider: http://supercollider.sourceforge.net/
- nsound: http://nsound.sourceforge.net/ (maybe the easiest)

playback through soundcard is possible with (I think) all of them.